# Registration form using JDBC and Servlet in java

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have problem accessing database with servlet java. I want to add users with an html registration form. this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Registration Page</title>
    <!---Custom CSS File--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>Registration Form</header>
      <form action="register" method="post" class="form">
      
        <div class="input-box">
          <label>Full Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="txtUname" placeholder="Enter full name" required />
        </div>

        <div class="input-box">
          <label>Email Address</label>
          <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter email address" required />
        </div>

        <div class="input-box">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="Pass" placeholder="Password" required />
        </div>
        <button>REGISTER</button>
      </form>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the servlet (RegistrationControllerServlet.java)

```
package com.loginpagedemo.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.loginpagedemo.dao.UserDao;
import com.loginpagedemo.daoimpl.UserDaoImpl;
import com.loginpagedemo.pojo.User;

@WebServlet("/register")
public class RegistrationControllerServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        
    
    String uname = request.getParameter("txtUname");
    String password = request.getParameter("Pass");
    String email = request.getParameter("Email");
    
    User u = new User(uname,password,email);
    
    UserDao daoImpl = new UserDaoImpl();
    
    
    if(daoImpl.addNewUser(u)) {
        response.sendRedirect("Success?msg=regsuccess");
    }
    else {
        response.sendRedirect("error?msg=regerror");
    }   
  }
}
```

This is the java class (User.java):

```
package com.loginpagedemo.pojo;

public class User {

    private String username;
    private String emailaddress;
    private String password;
    
    public User() {
    }
    
    public User(String username,String emailaddress,String password){
        this.username = username;
        this.emailaddress =emailaddress;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmailaddress() {
        return emailaddress;
    }

    public void setEmailaddress(String emailaddress) {
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is the java Interface (UserDao.java):

```
package com.loginpagedemo.dao;

import com.loginpagedemo.pojo.User;

public interface UserDao {

    boolean checkUserCredentials(User user);
    boolean addNewUser(User user);
}
```

This is the java class (DbConnection.java):

```
package com.loginpagedemo.connection;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DbConnection {
public static Connection getDatabaseConnection(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =
                DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/28thnovadv",
                        "root","ROOT@123");
        return con;
        }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the java class (UserDaoImpl.java):

```
package com.loginpagedemo.daoimpl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.loginpagedemo.connection.DbConnection;
import com.loginpagedemo.dao.UserDao;
import com.loginpagedemo.pojo.User;

public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Override
    public boolean checkUserCredentials(User user) {
        try(Connection con =
                    DbConnection.getDatabaseConnection()){
                PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE username=? AND email=? AND password=?");
                
                st.setString(1, user.getUsername());
                st.setString(2, user.getEmailaddress());
                st.setString(3, user.getPassword());
                
                ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery();
                
    if(rs.isBeforeFirst())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
            }
    catch(SQLException | NullPointerException exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }   
   }

    @Override
    public boolean addNewUser(User user) {
        try(Connection con =
                DbConnection.getDatabaseConnection()){
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO userdata VALUES(?,?,?)");
            
            st.setString(1, user.getUsername());
            st.setString(2, user.getEmailaddress());
            st.setString(3, user.getPassword());
            
            int count = st.executeUpdate();
            
            if(count > 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    catch(SQLException | NullPointerException exc){
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }   
  } 
}
```

This is the Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>LoginpageJDBC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>RegistartionFrom.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>registration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.loginpagedemo.controller.RegistrationControllerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>registration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojfxo.png)

[error after updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWweS.png)

I'm sorry that is a long question, but I am in despair

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
Looks like you're trying to access the wrong url

Comment: How do you build this?  It works fine for me other than it attempts to redirect to either `/Success?msg=regsuccess` or `/error?msg=regerror` after it does it's insert and they don't exist.  What server (i.e. Tomcat, Wildfly, etc) are you testing against?

Comment: I am using Tomcat on eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your implementation of method `dopost()` is wrong.
It should be `doPost()`.
https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-servlets/httpservlet.html
Like this:

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

You can also try to configure manually the servlet in `WEB-INF/web.xml`.
Something like:

```xml
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>registration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.loginpagedemo.controller.RegistrationControllerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>registration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

https://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/

Comment: Hey, I have updated my code but now it is showing this error

Comment: Ok, the `@WebServlet` annotation tries to configure the servlet for you, when you manually configure the servlet in `web.xml` you don't need the annotation. Remove it and see if it works.

Comment: No its not working again showing the same error